# Add captcha to a custom Sign In page for Azure ADB2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

Trying to add an additional claim to our custom Sign In page on Azure ADB2C (using custom policies) to hold a captcha response token. But the custom policy won't render the element on the page.

I've tried the sample here:
https://github.com/jasjeetsuri/B2C-IEF-Custom-Policies/tree/master/LocalAccounts%20-%20Captcha%20Integration

But the additional field doesn't get rendered on the UI. Everything else is working, the captcha appears on the UI and when I log in I can see my validation API being called with the default value 0. I just can't get a DOM element to be rendered by the policy so I can set the response token.

I've tried:

- Adding a custom User Attribute (e.g. captcha) and referring to it as extension_captcha
- Updating the ContentDefinition  to the latest
- Using  with the Required attribute set to True, this actually gave me an error message to say the value was missing however the field was never rendered on the page
- Changing the CombinedSignInAndSignUp to ClaimsExchange but this reverted the custom Sign In UI back to the Microsoft default layout

I've gone through documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

and here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

But no luck.

Does anyone know what the minimum config is to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I made the sample this way because it doesn’t work for combined sign in and sign up page. You would need two seperate policies and deep link between them.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft, this is a good example: [Sign-in and Sign-up policy with direct link to sign-up](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-up-deep-link) of using a deep link ? thanks